# App crashes at onActivityResult() api 31 Bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

So I'm trying to make an app that connects to Bluetooth but whatever I do I can't get the permission dialog to appear I tried the method provided by android using startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT); but it's deprecated so I did some research and found that I need to use  ActivityResultLauncher but the app crashes when trying to call it here is the code

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startForResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
            if (result != null && result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK){
                if (result.getData() != null ){
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

**Inside onCreate**

```
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager.class);
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device doesn't support Bluetooth
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device doesn't support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device does support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

            startForResult.launch(enableBtIntent);
            //startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

        }
```

**PS:** I don't care about older API as the app is just for me to control led strips in my room via Bluetooth

Comment: It would be extremely beneficial to post the stacktrace you get when it crashes.

Comment: any ideas on how to do that? couldn't find a way online... I'm testing the app directly on my phone via USB btw

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

after a lot of trial and error it finally worked and I have no idea how because I'm pretty sure I used this same code before and it kept crashing but now it doesn't so here is the entire MAinActivity.java

```
package com.example.ledcontroller;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
                if (isGranted) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission not Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // There are no request codes
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                }
            });


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Set Bluetooth status src
        ImageView BtUnchecked = findViewById(R.id.not_connected);
        ImageView BtChecked = findViewById(R.id.connected);


        //BtUnchecked.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_uncheck_grey);
        //BtChecked.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check);

        //Settings button function
        ImageButton sett = findViewById(R.id.settingsbtn);

        sett.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });

        //Color Picker button function
        ImageButton colorpick = findViewById(R.id.colorPickerbtn);

        colorpick.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ColorPickerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });

        //Modes button function
        ImageButton modes = findViewById(R.id.modesbtn);

        modes.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ModesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        });

        //Bluetooth button function

        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager.class);
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();



        ImageButton bluetooth = findViewById(R.id.bluetoothbtn);

        bluetooth.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    someActivityResultLauncher.launch(enableBtIntent);
                } else {
                    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
                }
            }if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                bluetoothAdapter.disable();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "if done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "else done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

If anyone knows any way to make the code better that would be appreciated!

EDIT: I updated the if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) to request permission in case you reinstall the app and the Bluetooth is already enabled so the app doesn't crash anymore when pressing the button

Comment: and missing permissions was exactly the reason i asked you for the stacktrace, so that i know the root cause of the crash and propose a solution.